# RSS Feed created using Zend_Feed - firefox prompts to download not display as RSS

Tags: zend-framework, feed

I've created an RSS feed using Zend_Feed.

It seems to have worked in that the resulting XML looks good. My problem is that Firefox won't recognise it as an RSS feed and instead prompts me to download the raw XML.

Trying it in IE gives the error "this feed contains code errors" with the following extra info:

`Invalid xml declaration.
 Line: 2 Character: 3`

< ? xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Note that I put the space between the < and the ? in the IE error as otherwise this line wasn't being shown in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The xml-declaration must be on the absolute first line in the output. I.e. no blank lines or spaces before the xml-declaration tag.

This is valid:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

This is not:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
```

Comment: Thanks - it looks like this is the problem as there is a blank line first. Not sure why Zend is doing that though...

Comment: It might not be Zend - make sure you don't have any errant whitespace in your PHP.

Comment: You are correct - it seems that a blank line after the closing ?> at the end of the PHP file was causing the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: You can safely omit the ?> at the end of PHP files to avoid this altogether

Answer (score 1):

Check whether `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` is the first line in the feed file. No empty lines or spaces!

Answer (score 0):

If PHP is spitting out any notices/warnings or such, those will malform the feed. Try setting error_reporting to zero before the feed is sent to test:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Comment: Alternatively, set error reporting to maximum, and fix the problem, rather than just hiding it.  error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);

Answer (score 0):

good rule of thumb when using php class files and such, never `?>` your class files.  Only use `?>` in template-type files where you are going to have regular output afterwards.  All of the major packages do this now for exactly the above reasoning.